# What's a faster and more memory-efficient way to read_csv a subset of files from a directory based upon a date pattern in their filename?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, dask

The code i have right now:

```
cols = ['X','Y','Z','W','A']
path = r'/Desktop/files'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/file*")
d_list = pd.date_range('2019-09-01','2020-09-09',freq='D').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
 
list1 = []
 
for i in d_list:      
    for filename in all_files:
        if i in filename:
            df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep='|',usecols=cols)
            list1.append(df)
 
data = pd.concat(list1, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This code takes a very long time to run, I assume I don't have enough memory.
Is there any other method to make it faster?
If anyone knows how I could use dask.dataframe and if that would help, but also keep the original dtypes of the variables, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of `d_list`  and `for i in d_list:`? Are you trying to loop through multiple directories? If so, that is not clear, and it appears you are doing it wrong. My answer is just for one folder.

Comment: d_list is a list of dates that i am interested in, for example, a file named "file_2018-12-01", is out of my range of dates, so it shouldn't be read.

Comment: you could probably speed that up significantly then, by creating a list first, because then you wouldn't have to loop through the directory 10 times. It's not possible to tell from your code wha the patttern of the filenames looks like, but you could do something like `all_files = glob.glob(path + "/file*2019-09-0*")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dask try the following:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

#This is an example of a common pattern you could have for your files, so that you can loop through them one time rather than loop through a list of dates 10x.
all_files = glob.glob(r'/Desktop/files/file*2019-09-0*.csv')

df = dd.concat([dd.read_csv(f, sep='|', usecols=cols) for f in all_files])
#df1 = df.compute() #returns a pandas dataframe from the dask dataframe
```

Pandas is essentially the same syntax:

```
import pandas as pd
all_files = glob.glob(r'/Desktop/files/file*2019-09-0*.csv')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', usecols=cols) for f in all_files])
```

Comment: I tried using your code with dask, but it doesn't return df, did you run this code? Did it return df for you?

Comment: @Mari I made up the filepath as I don't know what your files look like. When you do `print(all_files)` what do you see? @Mari this code works for me, I just ran it. If you want to return a pandas dataframe after reading in as a dask dataframe, then use `.compute()` e.g. `df_new = df.compute()` and then `df_new`

Comment: And, If you want to keep it as a dask dataframe, then dask just shows the column headers and data types. It doesn't show all of the data.